# How to read all data from cursor.execute() in python?

Tags: python, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

I use PyMysql to connect to my MySQL DB.

```
cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for (id,clientid,timestamp) in cursor:
    print id,clientid,timestamp
```

I want to sort the data based on timestamp ;like;

```
 sortedList = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x.timestamp, reverse=False)
```

but cursor returns rows. How can I return the whole data, so I can sort them based on any parameter?

p.s: Here data contains multiple rows like;
 `1, '1170', 'AS0001', 1, '1', datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 10, 56), Decimal('15185.7562'), Decimal('0.0000'), Decimal('19814.3181')`

Comment: First, check what `data` holds. Second, you probably want to sort on MySQL side, *not* in Python.

Comment: @randomir each tuple contains like  //1, '1170', 'AS0001', 1, '1', datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 15, 10, 56), Decimal('15185.7562'), Decimal('0.0000'), Decimal('19814.3181')// data

Comment: If the timestamp is the 5th element try `key=lambda x: x[5]`. I agree with @randomir though.

Comment: @Selcuk thanks that fixes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a plain old cursor you can just do cursor.fetchall(), like follows:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select a, b, c from bar")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Which outputs

```
[(1,2,3), (4,5,6), ...]
```

However, if you want to have the results in dictionary format, make sure to connect with:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(db='foo', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

In this case the results will be usable in your lambda, ie:

```
[{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3}, ...]
```

Comment: Do we have DictCursor in mysql-python-connector too?

Comment: yes, works the same except the connection should be specified with `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`